# TeeChart in VB.Net : Subclassing SeriesXYZPoint cannot assign X axis

Tags: teechart

I have a very simple class I'm using to subclass a SeriesXYZPoint in TeeChart vb.net

```
Imports Steema.TeeChart.Styles

Public Class CustomSeriesXYZPoint
    Inherits SeriesXYZPoint

    Public Sub New(X As Double, y As Double, z As Double, color As Color, flagged As Boolean)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.X = X
        Me.Y = y
        Me.Z = z
        Me.Color = color
        Me.flagged = flagged
    End Sub

    Public flagged As Boolean
End Class
```

When I try to assign to the X value at "Me.X = X" I get a nullReferenceException with no InnerException, even though I can see that "Me" is not null in the constructor (as you would hope...)

What I'm doing here should be really simple, and the error message I get is totally opaque. Any help would be awesome.

Edit: I get the same error when I run

```
    Dim thing As New SeriesXYZPoint
    thing.X = someValue
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SeriesXYZPoint` class is not a series type designed to be drawn in a chart. It's a class internally used to extend series functionality like `Custom3D` and derived. It needs a series associated to access that X property:

```
public class SeriesXYPoint : SeriesPoint
    //...
    public double X
    {
      get
      {
        return series.XValues[index];
      }
      //...
    }
}
```

Instead, you may want to extend `Points3D` series.